# How urllib.request.urlopen can work with a list of urls from a file?

Tags: python, pandas, urllib

I'm trying to get a list of url's code from a list to work with urlopen so I can iterate through them and work with each url.

I was able to do what I wanted perfectly with one url directly passed as an argument, but I want to be able to do the same with a list.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error
a = unique_urls.shape[0]
code = []
for i in range(0,a):
    try: 
        link = unique_urls.iloc[i,0]
        print(link)
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        status_code = format(e.code) 
        code.append(status_code) 
    else: 
        code.append('200')
print(code)
```

the error that I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-5d55726757b6> in <module>
      7         link = unique_urls.iloc[i,0]
      8         print(link)
----> 9         conn = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
     10     except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
     11         status_code = format(e.code)

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    513                 req.data = data
    514 
--> 515         req.timeout = timeout
    516         protocol = req.type
    517 

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

the data is:

```
0   url1
1   url2
2   url3
3   url4
4   url5
6   url6
7   url7
```

Comment: code looks okay, can you pls check if URLs in the list look okay to you if they cant be shared.I feel there is an integer in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much for fast reply, there was one value 0, that I removed. Now it works!

Comment: glad that it helped. You are welcome!